# How can i make the second camera to display in the bottom right corner in a small window only specific gameobject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added a new layer called it: CameraLayer.

I have one Camera as child under the first ThirdPersonController tagged as MainCamera. I set that this camera will show everything but the CameraLayer. In the inspector in Culling Mask. Everything marked but not the CameraLayer. And now i see in the Culling Mask: Mixed. This is the main camera showing everything.

The second camera i added as child under a Cube. And i want that this camera will show only the cube all the time in a small window in the bottom right corner in the Game View window while the game is running.
In this camera Culling Mask i selected only the CameraLayer and unselected the rest. So in this camera in the Culling Mask i see: CameraLayer.

But when i'm running the game i don't see the Camera under the Cube at all.

In the screenshot i marked in black where should the Camera under the Cube should be and display the Cube:

[image: Camera]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1)** Create a `Canvas` as child of your **first Camera** then create a `RawImage` as a child of this newly created `Canvas`.

This is this *Image* that will render your second camera video so move it at the bottom right of the view of your first camera.

**2)** Then Create a `RenderTexture` and assign it to the `Texture` property of the `RawImage` you just created

**3)** And finally assign this `RenderTexture` to the `Target Texture` property of your **second Camera**.

This **Target Texture** will be used by Unity as a buffer Texture for your Camera. Your scene should now look like this:

[image]